# Awesomium - отображение текущего url

Tags: c#, webbrowser, awesomium

```
using Awesomium.Core;
using Awesomium.Windows.Forms;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication13
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WebSession session = WebCore.CreateWebSession(new WebPreferences()
            {
               ProxyConfig = "socks4://52.52.109.113:1080"
             });
            var webControl = new WebControl();
            webControl.WebSession = session;
            panel1.Controls.Add(webControl);
            webControl.Size = new Size(700, 700);
            webControl.Location = new Point(10, 10);
            webControl.Source = new Uri("http://2ip.ru");
        }
    }
}
```

Как показать адрес сайта после загрузки ссылки с учетом JS редиректов? Допустим, что бы каждый редирект отображал ссылку в `textBox`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Можно использовать в стройный контрол `AddressBox`. Перенесите его с "Панели инструментов" на форму и задайте в  свойстве `AddressBox.WebControl` ваш WebControl.

2) Можно использовать Привязку данных. Для этого нужно перенести на форму 1 `WebControl` и один `TextBox`. Далее нажмите "F7", что бы перейти в CodeBehind и после `InitializeComponent();` укажите следующее

```
Binding bind = new Binding("Text", webControl1, "Source", true);
bind.DataSourceUpdateMode = DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged;           
textBox1.DataBindings.Add(bind);
```

3)Есть еще вариант перехватывать любый запросы `WebControl` и уже самому решать, что с ними делать. Для этого нужно реализовать интерфейс `IResourceInterceptor`

```
public class ManagerRequest : IResourceInterceptor
{
    public bool OnFilterNavigation(NavigationRequest request)
    {
        return false;
    }
    public ResourceResponse OnRequest(ResourceRequest request)
    {
        //в url и будет храниться адрес текущего запроса,
        //в том числе и загрузка Css/Js
        var url=request.Url.AbsoluteUri;          
        return null;
    }
}
```

Что бы все это заработало нужно после загрузки ядра задать нашу реализацию. подпишемся в загрузке формы на события загрузки ядра.
После `InitializeComponent();` пишем `WebCore.Initialized += WebCore_Initialized;` и добавляем метод

```
private void WebCore_Initialized(object sender, CoreStartEventArgs e)
{
   Awesomium.Core.WebCore.ResourceInterceptor = new ManagerRequest();
}
```